# Invoke-item not executing from scheduled task

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm wondering if some can point our why the last line in the script is not running via my scheduled task, the task runs at logon and as the system account.
the Line runs when I run it manually

I have also tried `start-process` instead of `invoke-item`

```
$username = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem | select-object   -ExpandProperty username 
$username = $username.replace(Domainname\', '')

$FaxClientService = 'printclient'
$FaxClientexec = 'C:\program files (x86)\fax\client\bin\printclient.exe'

$WantFile = "c:\users\'+$username+'\appdata\roaming\fax\client\PrintToFaxUserSettings.xml"
$FileExists = Test-Path $WantFile
If ($FileExists -eq $true)
{
    exit
}

Else
{
    # Insert username into XML
    $xml = new-object XML
    $xml.PreserveWhiteSpace = $true
    $xml.load("C:\temp\faxprinter\PrintToFaxUserSettings.xml")
    $xml.usersettings.username = $username
    $xml.PreserveWhiteSpace = $true
    $xml.save("C:\temp\faxprinter\PrintToFaxUserSettings.xml")
    Start-Sleep -s 10
    $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
    Stop-Process -processname $FaxClientService -Force
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
    New-Item c:\users\$username\appdata\roaming\fax -type directory
    New-Item c:\users\$username\appdata\roaming\fax\Client -type directory

    $source = 'c:\temp\faxprinter\PrintToFaxUserSettings.xml'
    $dest = 'c:\users\' + $username + '\appdata\roaming\fax\client\PrintToFaxUserSettings.xml'
    Copy-Item -Force $source $dest
    Start-Sleep -s 30
    Invoke-Item $FaxClientexec
}
```

Comment: Just a guess but try passing in credentials in your `Invoke-Item` command. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849794.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If the task

- Has a on logon-trigger
- Accesses the userprofile
- Includes an interactive action (starting an application)

then it really sounds like you would want it to run as `Users` and "only when a user is logged on" and not as `SYSTEM`.

Comment: The problem I have is, the script it failed when I attempted to run it from the run once key, that's why I chose system, and a scheduled task, I'm not sure it it was actually user rights or just UAC issues, I'll try it thought

Comment: I can't see UAC issues here. I would investigate the errors you got as you'll probably receive the same ones with my answer. The good thing with scheduled tasks is that you can run them manually in the console so you can tests them in the same context over and over. :-)

Comment: It seems that interactive requires a password, Something I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: Oh sorry, couldn't test this one. Try `users` as the account (use check names) so any user will run it. Just remember to also use "only when user is logged" :-)

Comment: Tried this but it stopped for a password prompt. I ended up switching this back to the runonce key and it worked.